# Not able to show View Container in Container View in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uiviewcontroller

I am taking reference from tutorial [here](https://github.com/iaaqib/ContainerView).

I have one View Controller which contains a Container View. On this Container View I have added Custom Segue i.e. FirstViewController. That means when I opens View Controller it by default shows FirstViewController. And on FirstViewController, I have a Button. And by clicking on this button I want to show SecondViewController  but I am not able to get this achieved. I have also added print command on Button click and it prints on console and not switch to another View. Please help.

I have created a delegate in FirstViewController and aa function which reference through ViewController.

**Code for FirstViewController.swift**

```
  protocol FirstViewDelegate: class {
    func sendToSecondViewController()

 }

   class FirstViewController: UIViewController {

     weak var delegate: FirstViewDelegate? = nil

     @IBAction func goToSecond(_ sender: UIButton) {

    print("test1")
     delegate?.sendToSecondViewController()

       }


    }
```

**Code for ViewController.swift**

```
      extension ViewController: FirstViewDelegate{

func sendToSecondViewController() {
    container.segueIdentifierReceivedFromParent("second")
}

     }
```

**And main.storyboard**

[image: StoryBoard Layout]

[image: ViewController connection with Container View]

[image: Add Custom Segue to Container]

[image: Add Segue]

Comment: Simply, Do you want to go another view controller?

Comment: Yes, But want to open it in same same container view

Answer (score 0):

Seems you have not set delegate of **FirstViewController** in **ViewController**. Something like:

```
<object of FirstViewController>.delegate = self (Inside ViewController)
```